# Can't Get my Buttons to Center

Tags: html, css

I've been having trouble getting my buttons to center in CSS. I know the correct code to do so but all I have tried so far hasn't worked. I think that something is interfering with the code to center it but after an hour of looking I haven't been able to figure out the issue.

Here's my HTML:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: BebasNeue;
  src: url('BebasNeue Regular.otf');
}

body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1400px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #DE1B1B;
  /* Red */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: BebasNeue, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: BebasNeue, sans-serif;
  color: #E9E581;
  background-image: url('classroomb.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

#heading {
  margin-top:
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

a {
  padding: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #DE1B1B;
  position: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ms. Houck's Math Class</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="HouckStyle1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Homework </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> HW Solutions </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Documents </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Calendar </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <center>
    <h1>
      <div id="heading">Ms. Houck's Math Classes<br><br><br><br></h1>
    </div>
  </center>
  <p>
    Welcome students! Please use the navigation bar at the top of the page to access what you need. You can also access the homework and schedule by clicking the links below. <br>
    <br><a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Py9kSEH-vaubUM_r_oZ4lwf4pZn6TX2FXH8_-O7gLDw/edit" class="button">Homework</a>
    <a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-nZ04EpMx69QUFETFlJU213bEU" class="button">Homework Answers</a>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `position: center`? Where did you get this from?

Comment: `<center>` has been long deprecated.

Comment: Please be more clear and put some images about the current issue and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: *I know the correct code to do so but all I have tried so far hasn't worked.* If it doesn't work, then I guess you do **not** know the correct code to do so. Anyway, please reduce your sample code to a few dozen lines of code so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

The best and the easiest way is to use `flexbox` and use `justify-content:center` which aligns the items in the center of the main axis. You can learn more about `flexbox` [here.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-6)

Answer (score 1):

You could just wrap the two buttons in a new `<div>` which you then tell to have its content centered:

Add to css:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="center">
    <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Py9kSEH-vaubUM_r_oZ4lwf4pZn6TX2FXH8_-O7gLDw/edit" class="button">Homework</a>
    <a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-nZ04EpMx69QUFETFlJU213bEU" class="button">Homework Answers</a>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLh5m4pa/)

Please consider using `<div class="center">` instead of [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) `<center>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use flexbox and `justify-content: center;` on the `navigation ul` (took out div)
Use margin on the `li a` to modify spacing.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: BebasNeue;
  src: url('BebasNeue Regular.otf');
}

body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1400px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #DE1B1B;
  /* Red */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: BebasNeue, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: BebasNeue, sans-serif;
  color: #E9E581;
  background-image: url('classroomb.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

#heading {
  margin-top:
}

header ul {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

a {
  padding: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #DE1B1B;
  position: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ms. Houck's Math Class</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="HouckStyle1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Homework </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> HW Solutions </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Documents </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Calendar </a></li>
      </ul>
  
  </header>
  <center>
    <h1>
      <div id="heading">Ms. Houck's Math Classes<br><br><br><br></h1>
    </div>
  </center>
  <p>
    Welcome students! Please use the navigation bar at the top of the page to access what you need. You can also access the homework and schedule by clicking the links below. <br>
    <br><a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Py9kSEH-vaubUM_r_oZ4lwf4pZn6TX2FXH8_-O7gLDw/edit" class="button">Homework</a>
    <a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-nZ04EpMx69QUFETFlJU213bEU" class="button">Homework Answers</a>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: BebasNeue;
  src: url('BebasNeue Regular.otf');
}

body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1400px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #DE1B1B;
  /* Red */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: BebasNeue, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: BebasNeue, sans-serif;
  color: #E9E581;
  background-image: url('classroomb.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}


li {
  display: inline;
}

a {
  padding: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #DE1B1B;
  position: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
.center{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Homework </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> HW Solutions </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Documents </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Calendar </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
<br/>

<div class="center"><h1>Ms. Houck's Math Classes</h1></div><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<p>
    Welcome students! Please use the navigation bar at the top of the page to access what you need. You can also access the homework and
    schedule by clicking the links below. 
</p>
<br><br>
<div class="center">
<a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Py9kSEH-vaubUM_r_oZ4lwf4pZn6TX2FXH8_-O7gLDw/edit" class="button">Homework</a>
    <a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-nZ04EpMx69QUFETFlJU213bEU" class="button">Homework Answers</a></div>
```

---

1. Your buttons are not centered. They are in `<p>` code.
2. If you want to center them - make other block with align tag
3. `<center>` tag is deprecated, should not use this

Comment: Are you going to explain your answer, or did you want everyone to just play a game of spot-the-difference?